# Forcing reference

Tags: reference-request, logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

Who first proved that, over ZF, the statement

> (1) The reals are well-orderable

is strictly stronger than the statement

> (2) Every real-indexed family of nonempty sets of reals has a choice function?

The separation is of course implied by the consistency of large cardinals - (2)+$\neg$(1) is a consequence of AD$_\mathbb{R}$ - but a large-cardinal-free proof seems nontrivial, and I'm curious who first came up with such a thing. (To answer the implicit question, I've thought about it a little and can't come up with the proof myself, although I'm probably just being slow - I remember being told that the  separation is provable with no consistency assumptions, and I *think* I recall being shown a fairly straightforward argument for it.)

Comment: Maybe a better title is in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I googled the second statement, and the first article to come up was the following:

> *J. Truss*, [**The axiom of choice for linearly ordered families**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=480029), *Fund. Math.* **99** (1978), no. 2, 133--139.

Which you can also find [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm99/fm99114.pdf). You're looking for Theorem 4 (which is in the third section).

Comment: This is great, thanks!